# Program in freestanding environment

Tags: c++

Quote from 3.6.1/1 N3797:

> A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the
>   designated start of the program. It is implementation-defined whether
>   a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main
>   function.

Are "a program" and "a program in a freestanding environment" different things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is often used in embedded systems programming. There you might encounter a(n example of) lack of "host environment" in which case you're running in a **free standing evironment**.

What this practically means is that, apart from lack of OS I/O, threading etc libraries is that some facilities are unavailable and it requires assembly start-up code to get you to `main()`; Characteristic differences (just to get an idea) are

- Exceptions require code to unwind the stack while looking for an appropriate exception handler to handle the exception. Usually, this code is linked in with your C++ application, but in a freestanding kernel the code must be provided manually.
- You'd have to write your own heap manager (new/delete) if you wanted to create objects at runtime and your own scheduler if you wanted more than one thread

So [considerations](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/ESC_San_Jose_98_401_paper.pdf), techniques and [application domain](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36907/How-to-develop-your-own-Boot-Loader) may vary but a program is a program.

Comment: That is in some embedded system program the main function may be absence. Is it true?

Comment: It would be better if you've get a little example of such program. Can you improve the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a program and a program in a freestanding environment are different things. In freestanding environment you do not have any built-in library to be used.